# this is my sp ..am getting result consisted of more than one row.please help me

Tags: mysql

this is my sp when i run it am getting error:

> result consisted of multiple rows

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `fourandfive`(IN choice varchar(10), IN upcstring varchar(100), IN Skustring varchar(100) )
BEGIN
set @numberofUpcs = length(upcstring);
set @numberofSkus = length(Skustring);
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS upcs;
create temporary table upcs (upcValue varchar(20));

while (@numberofUpcs>0) do

set @oneupc = substring_index(upcstring,',',1); 

insert into upcs values(@oneupc);

set @next = substr(upcstring,1,length(@oneupc)+1);

set upcstring = replace(upcstring,@next,'');

#select @next, @oneupc, upcstring;



set @numberofUpcs = length(upcstring);


end while;



DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS skus;
create temporary table skus (skuValue varchar(20));

while (@numberofSkus>0) do

set @onesku = substring_index(Skustring,',',1); 

insert into skus values(@onesku);

set @next = substr(Skustring,1,length(@onesku)+1);

set Skustring = replace(Skustring,@next,'');

#select @next, @oneupc, upcstring;



set @numberofSkus = length(Skustring);


end while;




select count(*) from upcs into @upclen;


#final loop

while(@upclen>=1) do

select upcValue into @Upc from upcs limit 1;
select skuValue into @Sku from skus limit 1;


IF(choice='four') THEN

select shipping into @shipping from store_data where upc = @Upc and sku = @Sku limit 1;
select (price+@shipping) into @reprice from prices where upc = @Upc and sku = @Sku limit 1;
update revised_price set price = @reprice where upc = @Upc;
delete from skus where skuValue = @Sku;
set @Sku = 0;

#select @shipping,@reprice;


ELSE IF(choice = 'five') then
select min(price) into @minimumprice from prices where upc= @Upc group by upc;
update revised_price set price = @minimumprice where upc = @Upc;
end if;
end if;
set @upclen = @upclen-1;
delete from upcs where upcValue = @Upc;
set @Upc = 0;
end while;
drop table upcs;
drop table skus;

END
```

Comment: Pls do not expect us to locate where the error is raised, but point us to the location!

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP PROCEDURE fourandfive;
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE fourandfive(IN choice varchar(10),IN upcstring VARCHAR(255),IN Skustring varchar(100))
BEGIN
set @numberofUpcs = length(upcstring);
set @numberofSkus = length(Skustring);
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS upcs;
create temporary table upcs (upcValue varchar(20));

while (@numberofUpcs>0) do

set @oneupc = substring_index(upcstring,',',1); 

insert into upcs values(@oneupc);

set @next = substr(upcstring,1,length(@oneupc)+1);

set upcstring = replace(upcstring,@next,'');

#select @next, @oneupc, upcstring;



set @numberofUpcs = length(upcstring);


end while;



DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS skus;
create temporary table skus (skuValue varchar(20));

while (@numberofSkus>0) do

set @onesku = substring_index(Skustring,',',1); 

insert into skus values(@onesku);

set @next = substr(Skustring,1,length(@onesku)+1);

set Skustring = replace(Skustring,@next,'');

#select @next, @oneupc, upcstring;



set @numberofSkus = length(Skustring);


end while;




select count(*) from upcs into @upclen;


#final loop

while(@upclen>=1) do

select upcValue into @Upc from upcs limit 1;
select skuValue into @Sku from skus limit 1;


IF(choice='four') THEN

select shipping into @shipping from store_data where upc = @Upc and sku = @Sku limit 1;
select (price+@shipping) into @reprice from prices where upc = @Upc and sku = @Sku limit 1;
update revised_price set price = @reprice where upc = @Upc;
delete from skus where skuValue = @Sku;
set @Sku = 0;

#select @shipping,@reprice;


ELSE IF(choice = 'five') then
select min(price) into @minimumprice from prices where upc= @Upc;
update revised_price set price = @minimumprice where upc = @Upc;
end if;
end if;
set @upclen = @upclen-1;
delete from upcs where upcValue = @Upc;
set @Upc = 0;
end while;
drop table upcs;
drop table skus;

END
```

Just try above code.

You had made

```
select min(price) into @minimumprice from prices where upc= @Upc group by upc;
```

so it will generate multiple row instead of that you have to try

```
select min(price) into @minimumprice from prices where upc= @Upc ;
```

Hope this will helps.